# How to optimize this string replacement code

Tags: matlab

I have an algorithm whose intermediate step is to replace a substring with another substring. To be precise I have a string HBIN_NEW and I have another string P. I want to replace every 6th,7th,8th element of the string HREP with the 1st,2nd,3rd element of PBIN_NEW. For this i have written the code

```
     For example If PBIN_NEW='1111111101010101' and HBIN_NEW='1111100010101010' 
   then the new string HREP
   should be HREP='1111111110101101' 
      for k=1:8:262144*8
   HREP=strrep(HBIN_NEW,HBIN_NEW(k+5:k+7),PBIN_NEW(k:k+2));
end
```

Is this code correct to implement the above idea. And if yes, it is taking a long time do this replacement scheme, can somebody suggest some optimized way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wording on the question is still a bit awkward, and I'm not exactly sure how to get the example HREP given the wording, but most likely `strrep` is overkill for what it sounds like you are trying to do. A simple loop with assignments would be fine:

```
HREP = HBIN_NEW;
for k=1:8:length(HBIN_NEW)
   HREP(k+5:k+7) = PBIN_NEW(k:k+2);
end
```

Often times though it can be better to just enumerate the position assignments and avoid the loop. So instead you have something like this:

```
HREP = HBIN_NEW;
HREP(6:8:end) = PBIN_NEW(1:8:end);
HREP(7:8:end) = PBIN_NEW(2:8:end);
HREP(8:8:end) = PBIN_NEW(3:8:end);
```

I think that does what you want, or should get you close enough ...

Finally, a bit of unsolicited style advice. Although Matlab doesn't have a very strict code style guide, most likely the use of all caps with underscores is not the best way of naming your variables. I personally prefer lowercase with underscores, e.g. `pbin_new` and only use capitalized words for constants ...